# Any REAL open source alternatives to C#/MVC3?

Tags: linux, frameworks, web

I work with C# and MVC3 most every day and I absolutly love the whole experience.. All the way from starting visual studio to deploying it on IIS and working in MSSQL studio..

Now when I get home I tend to want to do some other not so well funded projects and it's also fun to learn new languages and styles.. so I am wondering are there any really good viable open source alternatives to Visual Studio - C#/MVC3.

I am well versed in MySQL and Apache but what are my options when it comes to a rock solid IDE and framework?

In order to make suggestions a little simpler here are some of the criteria I though of.

- The framework needs to be proven, ie used on many production sites & have a big community.
- There needs to be an IDE which supports everything about the framework (auto completion, references, break points, help, publish to server, etc..).
- I dont want to write any type of SQL, in MVC3 i write lambda or LINQ, something similar to this would be nice.
- OO language, Java/Python would be nice.
- Be fast to work with.
- Would prefeer if it can run on Apache & MySQL.

Comment: How about Ruby and Rails? It has full MVC, is a big Linux framework, and integrates well with other Linux techologys like MySQL and Apache. It would probably fit your needs well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct equivalent to the Microsoft enterprise stack is the Java enterprise stack. The two have been battling it out for getting on for two decades now!

Java doesn't have a standard IDE, but i would suggest that Eclipse is something of a de facto standard; i'm not saying that it's the best, just that it has the widest adoption.

Java also doesn't have a standard MVC framework; the only standard web framework is JSF, which is more heavyweight. Nonetheless, there are some very popular and well-established frameworks which fill this gap: the most popular is Struts 2, and i will add a recommendation for Stripes.

Java doesn't have a standard server which is an equivalent of IIS, but it has a standard for servers, and there are many implementations: for simple servlet containers, there are Tomcat and Jetty, and for fully-fledged application servers, there are JBoss, GlassFish, and a variety of commercial products. My personal recommendation would be for JBoss AS7; it does everything the traditional app server can do, but it has the startup speed, memory use, and ease of configuration of the simple servlet containers.

To address your bullets specifically:

- Java is used on many production sites, and has a big community.
- Eclipse does everything you can imagine for Java (autocompletion, navigation, debugging, documentation, refactoring - my impression is that it does this better than VS does), and has integrations with many aspects of the EE stack (like building and deploying web applications), plus a decent database development mode.
- If you use JPA for persistence, then you can get by without writing any SQL. The JPA implementation will generate the DDL to set up the database, and the queries to load and store objects. If you want to do complex queries, you can either write them in JPQL (which is like a more object-friendly SQL), or use an API to build queries out of objects. I don't think this is as good as LINQ, sadly.
- Java is reasonably object-oriented.
- Java is productive in skilled hands (i assume this is what you mean by "fast to work with"). It has historically not been as fast at going from zero to a running website as something like Ruby on Rails, but i think the gap has narrowed a lot with the current generation of tools, and there is a phenomenal depth of tools and libraries that can keep you productive in later stages of an application's lifecycle.

It can certainly work with Apache and MySQL, although you will need a servlet container or app server in the mix too. My company uses Apache, Tomcat, and MySQL for our product, for example. I would strongly suggest you use PostgreSQL instead of MySQL, because MySQL is, frankly, terrible, but you can certainly use MySQL if you really want to!

Comment: Yes and no. If you ask me, the native development stacks (like RoR, PHP, Python, and other Linux languages give much nicer programing experiences and much quicker programing.

Comment: @Linuxios: You're certainly not alone in thinking that!

Comment: :). Definitely. I had a short stint in C#, and it was not pleasant.

Comment: I will look into those frameworks for Java, Eclipse is already installed ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to learn a new language, Ruby on Rails is the way to go. Rails is a big community, Ruby is a big community, and I think that it can fit your specifications:

- Rails is *huge*
- Try RubyMine, Aptana, or do it the Linux way: vim!
- ActiveRecord should do that for you with its dynamic query methods
- Ruby is the OO of all OO, if you ask me.
- Ruby and Rails are both known for fast prototyping and development
- Rails is built for MySQL and Apache

Comment: I will definitely consider RoR, have looked at them before, and they do have a few big sites that use them. http://www.developerdrive.com/2011/09/20-best-sites-built-with-ruby-on-rails/.

Comment: @wokawaka: Yeah. I Would definitely suggest RoR for web dev n the server side. Ruby is an incredible language, and really just a joy to program in.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are looking at this from a hobbyist perspective have you considered Visual C# Express and Visual Web Developer Express?

It's a free to use package from Microsoft which comes with MVC and ASP.NET and provides that refined working environment you're after with no cost. You also get the impressive IISExpress which is a light version of the full IIS.